# How can i close my Connections after the caller finishes with them?

Tags: c#, database, connection, oledb

---

I have created the following method:

```
 public System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader GetReader(string sqlQuery)
  {

          System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection myConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
          LoadConnectionStrings();
          myConnection.ConnectionString = ConnectionString;
          myConnection.Open();
          System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand myCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sqlQuery, myConnection);
          System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader myReader = null;
          myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

          return myReader;

  }
```

---

Several thousand lines of code rely on it, and i guess i wasn't really thinking when i implemented it...

Anyway,. If i retrieve a reader this way i have no way of closing the connection, and if i close the connection before the reader has called the read() method it will blow up when it goes to read and say that the connection to the database needs to be Open.

The question is, how can i close connection from previous bodies of code? Or all connections in general maybe..

From what I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227005/what-happens-if-i-leave-a-database-connection-open-in-an-asp-net-web-page) if you don't specifically call 'close()' it doesn't get closed, and if you're using an access 2003 file it kind of leaves you in a world of hurt

Comment: Why not closing just before the return?

Comment: @Dor because it hasn't consumed any data at that point

Comment: unfortunately, You cannot  :/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In that scenario, the connection needs to stay open for the reader to work - however, there is an overload to ExecuteReader that lets you specify a flag for the reader to close the connection when the reader is closed:

```
myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
```

This allows a caller to use:

```
using(var reader = GetReader(query)) {
    //...
}
```

And the connection will be closed cleanly when the caller is done with the reader.

Comment: Who would of thought 2 words would save thousands of lines of code ^_^

Comment: Nevertheless, if you have a method that returns an `IDataReader` it needs to include a try/catch which closes the connection in case `command.ExecuteReader` throws.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it solves your problem totally, but you could use the [IDBcommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/68etdec0.aspx) overload.

If you pass `CommandBehavior.CloseConnection` to that, the database connection will be closed when your reader is closed.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Marc, but want to point out a deficiency with your approach.

This mechanism hides the connection from the caller, so the caller can't use it for other operations against the database. It also scopes the connection to the lifetime of the reader, so that if any other action were to be taken, they would have to occur before disposing of the reader.

It might be better to have the caller control the connection, and simply pass the connection into the GetReader method.

Answer (score 1):

I use do something like:

```
IDataReader GetReader(...)
{
    IDbConnection connection = ...;
    try
    {
        IDbCommand command = ...;
        command.Connection = connection;
        connection.Open();
        return command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
    }
    catch
    {
        connection.Close();
        throw;
    }
}
```

This doesn't close the `IDbCommand`, but in my experience this is OK as long as the connection is closed.